# How to see website for seeing it as on different country

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, localization, globalization

I am working on the multilingual website. Generally I use microsoft.com pattern but problem is that i am not able to find how looks microsoft.com when some one open not supported by CultureInfo. Ie. What url and looks when some one open microsoft.com in kenya.

I am Indian. So that I am not able to open for Kenya website for microsoft.com.

Is any simulator available which shows how looks when website open based on country

Comment: Why not use a proxy server?

Comment: are you talking about change Proxy Server setting into browser ? or I missing something

Comment: Have you simply tried entering the Kenyan URL to visit the site? BTW. I always thought, that you have the location switcher in the upper right corner. That let me visit US MSDN although I live in Poland...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting Browser Language based on your requirement.

For IE - Tools->Internet Options->Language Preference

[image]

Comment: Thanks for Reply. I want Url Pattern for kenya or country which are not fall in CultureInfo so I can design according my website. For SEO and Folder Structure and other related things